# Riesz map between Sobolev space and its dual

Tags: self-learning, sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems

I'm asked to find the Riesz's map:

$$R:H^1_0(\Omega) \rightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)  $$
$$R: u \mapsto F_u \quad \text{s.t.} \quad <F_u,v>_*= (u_F,v)_{H_0^1} \ \ \forall v \in H_0^1 $$

I chose $(u,v)_{H_0^1} = (\nabla u, \nabla v)_{L^2}$

Here's my thoughts: I need to find $F_u$:

$$(u,v)_{H_0^1} = <F_u,v>_* \forall v \in H_0^1 $$
$$-\Delta u =F_u$$

And this would be my solution, $R=-\Delta$

However, I found online that $R=I-\Delta$  ($I$ being the identity)

Can someone explain to me why my reasoning is wrong and how to find such a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use $(u, v)_{H_0^1} = (\nabla u, \nabla v)_{L^2}$, you get $R = -\Delta$, as you have shown.

And there is another scalar product on $H_0^1$, such that $R = I - \Delta$. Which one?

Comment: The other one is $(u,v)_{L^2} + (\nabla u,\nabla v)_{L^2}$.
Note that (only) for $\Omega$ bounded the Friedrich's inequality tells you that both scalar products give equivalent norms for $H_0^1(\Omega)$.